# How to edit a specific line in a text file using Pascal

Tags: freepascal

I am struggling to replace a specific line of text with my text from my program. So far, all I have is opening the file for editing...I tried searching on the internet but the closest one I could find was this: http://wiki.freepascal.org/File_Handling_In_Pascal. The page has everything about appending new texts under a line in an existing file and creating an entirely new file for adding texts into, but not for a specific line in an existing file...

```
var musicfile: TextFile;    
AssignFile(musicfile, 'AlbumList.dat');
Append(musicfile);
WriteLn(musicfile, 'A text a want to replace line 5 with, but I dont know how to find line 5...');
Close(musicfile);
```

Comment: You can't. You have to rewrite the entire file following the point where you edit. Unless of course you are replacing the same number of characters.

Comment: Oh, ok. I saw this in a different post as well, but I wasn't sure if that was the answer...Is there any chance you know why we have to do it in such an inefficient way?

Comment: Because the file is a stream of characters

Comment: @KHang: it would be simpler if every line had the same length, but they don't. Then you could simply replace one line for another without "moving" the rest, and you could random access them. But storing text that way would be an enormous waste of space. So text is a continous stream of characters, including linefeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new file and copy all the lines except the one you want to replace. Like this:

```
var musicfile: TextFile;
    newfile: TextFile;
    line: string[100]; // long enough to hold the longest line in the file
    i: word; // counter for the lines

AssignFile(musicfile, 'AlbumList.dat');
AssignFile(newfile, 'AlbumList(1).dat'); // create new file

Reset(musicfile);
Rewrite(newfile); // open the new file for writing

i := 0 // we are at the 1st (index from zero) line

while not eof(musicfile) do begin
    readln(musicfile, line); // read the line into a variable
    if (i = 4) then // if we are at the 5th line, replace line
        writeln(newfile, 'The string which should replace the 5th line')
    else // just copy the line
        writeln(newfile, line);
    i := i + 1;
end;

Close(musicfile);
Close(newfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone who doesn't want to create a new file but wants to rewrite an old one I use TStringList (tested in lazarus btw):

```
var fileStrList:TStringList;
begin
  fileStrList:= TStringList.Create;  //creating the TStringList
  try
    fileStrList.LoadFromFile('AlbumList.dat');  //Loading file into TStringList
    fileStrList[4]:='Text you want to replace line 5 with';  //rewriting line 5
    fileStrList.SaveToFile('AlbumList.dat');    //saving rewritted TStringList to file
  finally
    fileStrList.Free;  //freeing the TStringList !don't forget about this!
  end;
end;
```